# MATLAB inner join two tables treating NaN entries as identical

Tags: matlab, join, inner-join, nan

I would like to innerjoin multiple tables where key columns contain many NaN values, and merging the tables remove these entries since NaNs are not considered identical.

I would like to innerjoin tables treating key columns' NaN entries identical.
Below example demonstrates the problem I am having:

```
>> A = table({'a' 'b' 'd' 'e'}',[123, 456, 789, NaN]',[4 5 6 7]', 'VariableNames', {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Var1'})
A =
  4×3 table
    Key1    Key2    Var1
    ____    ____    ____
    'a'     123      4  
    'b'     456      5  
    'd'     789      6  
    'e'     NaN      7  

>> B = table({'a' 'b' 'd' 'e'}', [123, 456, 789, NaN]', [1 2 3 4]', 'VariableNames', {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Var2'})
B =
  4×3 table
    Key1    Key2    Var2
    ____    ____    ____
    'a'     123      1  
    'b'     456      2  
    'd'     789      3  
    'e'     NaN      4  

>> innerjoin(A,B)
ans =
  3×4 table
    Key1    Key2    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____    ____    ____
    'a'     123      4       1  
    'b'     456      5       2  
    'd'     789      6       3
```

Desired output is below where Key columns NaN values are treated identical hence performing inner join on the entry where Key1 is 'e' and Key2 is NaN.

```
>> innerjoin(A,B)
ans =
  3×4 table
    Key1    Key2    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____    ____    ____
    'a'     123      4       1  
    'b'     456      5       2  
    'd'     789      6       3  
    'e'     NaN      7       4
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Replacing `NaN` by `inf` does what you want. Is that an option for you? You can then replace back

Comment: Further to Luis' comment, you can do this easily by indexing with the `isnan` and `isinf` functions.

Comment: @user32147 Glad it works. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `NaN` by `inf`, apply `innerjoin`, and then replace back:

```
A.Key2(isnan(A.Key2)) = inf;
B.Key2(isnan(B.Key2)) = inf;
result = innerjoin(A,B);
result.Key2(isinf(result.Key2)) = NaN;
```